# player.setDataSource(URL); dando erro

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tenho o código abaixo que abre uma **URL** de **Streaming** de uma **rádio web** e toca/pausa ela.

Tenho e erros neste `código` que não acho de jeito nenhum e peço a ajuda de vocês.

```
package carcleo.com.player;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.IOException;

public class player extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer player;
    private String URL;
    private Button btnPlayPause;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);

        URL               = "rtsp://cdn-the-2.musicradio.com:80/LiveAudio/Capital";
        btnPlayPause      = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.btnPlayPause);

        btnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    btnPlayPause.setText("Carregando...");
                    if (player == null) player = new MediaPlayer();
                    tocaPausa();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void tocaPausa () throws IOException {

        if (!player.isPlaying()) {

            player.setDataSource(URL);

            player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                }
            });

            player.prepare();
            player.start();
            btnPlayPause.setText("Pausar");

        } else {

            player.pause();
            btnPlayPause.setText("Tocar");

        }
    }
}
```

O 2 problemas são:

A) No **onCreate** tenho o **setOnClickListener** do botão que tenta alterar seu texto. Simplesmente não funciona, o texto não muda, mas a linha debaixo é executada normalmente.

```
    btnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                btnPlayPause.setText("Carregando...");
                if (player == null) player = new MediaPlayer();
                tocaPausa();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Experimentei colocar

```
btnPlayPause.setText("Carregando...");
```

dentro de:

```
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

            btnPlayPause.setText("Carregando...");
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
        }
    });
```

mas deu no mesmo.

B) Bom, aqui é mais difícil. Quando abro o player, clico no botão e após uns 12 segundos a rádio começa a tocar, quando clico no botão novamente, a rádio é pausada normalmente. Mas quando clico novamente para tocar de novo, dá erro na linha 43 dento do método `tocaPausa()`.

```
player.setDataSource(URL);
```

Eis o erro:

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: carcleo.com.player, PID: 365
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.nativeSetDataSource(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1078)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1039)
        at carcleo.com.player.player.tocaPausa(player.java:43)
        at carcleo.com.player.player.access$200(player.java:10)
        at carcleo.com.player.player$1.onClick(player.java:30)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5640)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22455)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Comment: Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer#java) do android esse error ocorre quando o arquivo indicado no `setDataSource` não existe, verifica se a `url` esta correta. Outra coisa é que talvez você precise informar o `setAudioStreamType`.

Comment: como disse, ao clicar pela primeira vez no botão, a rádio toca normalmente, isso me leva a acreditar que a url está ok.

Comment: coloca um `log` no `if` outro no `else` da sua `tocaPausa`, acho que a segunda vez ele esta passando pelo `else` pq acredido que isso ainda e verdadeiro `player.isPlaying()` porque você apenas deu `pause`.

Comment: Se for o caso a para voltar a tocar depois de um `pause` você precisa chamar a função `start`.

Comment: passou pelo primeiro bloco mesmo. tanto que travou na linha da URL. Fiz o teste do Log aqui

Comment: Então tenta guardar algo indicando que esta em `pause`, e dentro da sua função `tocaPausa` se estiver em `pause` chame apenas o `start` para ver se funciona.

Comment: uma outra opção é ao invés de dar `pause` chamar  `mediaPlayer.stop(); mediaPlayer.reset();`

Comment: descobri! note que toda vez que eu clico em play novamente, o player precisa ser  criado novamente. ai está o erro

Comment: adicionei 

            if (player != null) {
                player.reset();
                player.release();
                player = null;
            }
ao final

Comment: mas isso me trouxe outro problema, o carregamento precicsa ser feito novamente.